# Is there an attribute similar to OutputCache that I can use on normal C# methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I like how I can use [OutputCache] on my controller actions.

I have a few methods that aren't controller actions that I would like to add simple caching to, is there something similar to [OutputCache] that I could use on non-controller actions?  I have a method which hits a web-service that I want cached independently of the controller action that displays its data.

I just want an attribute which is a wrapper around HttpContext cache for normal methods.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there is nothing built-in. But you could build one if you will. If you are using .NET 4.0 you could use the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) assembly which provides many useful methods for caching data in .NET applications (not only web applications). You could also take a look at a technique called [function memoization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/26/function-memoization.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.cacheduration.aspx in your webservice.