# How to cache method returned value in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm building a web app which is selecting a lot of information from the database, and returns it. I'd like to store the returned value from the method which returns the tables from the database for 15 minutes, but it doesn't work using a `OutputCache` Filter:

```
[OutputCache(duration=900)]
private DataTable[] GetInfoTables() {...}
```

the method does work, just find, but when I add anything to one of the tables (after first logging into site and view them) it refreshes immediately and I'd like it to cache for 15 minutes.
I cannot cache the `public ActionResult Index()` because it checks for `Session`s value.
Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [OutputCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.outputcache?view=netframework-4.7.2)? It doesn't say that it can just cache the results of any method. You should probably look into the [Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache?view=netframework-4.7.2) object instead.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) article it does work for string methods

Comment: No, it doesn't say that. An action methods on a controller is not like any regular method. The framework calls the action method, and can check before it does so whether there is cached content or not. If you're calling a random method, then the responsibility is on you to implement the cache handling. They help you out with a place to store the objects you with to cache, but it's up to you to wire it up properly. Reread all of that documentation more carefully.

Comment: Do you still need help ?

Answer (score 4):

### Summary :

- I'm not aware of a way to :
- make **OutputCache** work with normal C# method
- **but** you can hack around it :
- you can use **MemoryCache** for normal C# method

### Solution

- Import  **System.Runtime.Caching** (or use VS Intense )
- Then:

```
     private DataTable[] GetInfoTables()
        {

            ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            var dataTable = cache["DataTable"] as DataTable[];
            if (dataTable == null)
            {
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
                dataTable =  getDataTable() ;
                cache.Set("DataTable", dataTable , policy);
            }

            return dataTable ;
        }
```

### Screenshot

I test the Solution using EF and sql server

[image]

[image]

### References

- [c# - MemoryCache AbsoluteExpiration acting strange - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630168/memorycache-absoluteexpiration-acting-strange)
- [MemoryCache Class (System.Runtime.Caching) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [asp.net mvc - Is there an attribute similar to OutputCache that I can use on normal C# methods? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223643/is-there-an-attribute-similar-to-outputcache-that-i-can-use-on-normal-c-sharp-me)
- [Improving Performance with Output Caching (C#) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)
- [c# - Scope of static Variable in multi-user ASP.NET web application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154892/scope-of-static-variable-in-multi-user-asp-net-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Output Cache stores the rendered HTML output. Therefore, you cannot use it for functions, methods etc.

I started using [CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager) library, which gives a unique interface for caching data in different cache providers. I'd suggest to have a look.

Other direct options are discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343899/how-to-cache-data-in-a-mvc-application)